Which programming language first used negative indexing to mean counting from the end?
Negative indexing is a well-known feature of Python, for example a[-1] gets the last element of list a. Which programming language was the first to do this? (FORTRAN has supported arbitrary indexing for a long time, but -1 is simply another index. This 1965 article proposes that behavior as an extension to FORTRAN II.)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I definitely used this feature in some scripting and editing languages in the early 80's and/or late 70's.

Negative indexes are just ordinary indexes in languages that are not opinionated about the starting index.  In Algol 60, foo[-1] is perfectly fine given the declaration array foo[-10:10].

@dave yes, that's what the whole comment chain was about.

The comment chain that was moved to oblivion aka 'chat' ?  I see no mention there of negative values being legitimate indexes in some languages, only that it was likely an out-of-bound reference (which may or may not be detected).

@dave yes you're right. I confused it with my original question which mentioned arbitrary indices in FORTRAN.

@dave: You can also do it in C with tricks like int foo[LEN]; int* foo_end = foo + LEN; foo_end[-1] = 42;.

Tcl (1988) uses the token end to signify the end of the list. So end-1 is the 2nd from the end. It's basically zero based indexing from the end (note end-0 is a valid index) which I prefer unlike one based indexing if purely negative indexing is used.

As a note: supporting negative indices like this takes time for every index to do the conditional check.  I expect the pattern is much more common in languages which permit a little extra time on each index (such as for bounds checking).

@CortAmmon: If, as I suspect, the practice originated with languages that supported power-of-two modular addressing, a single extra masking step would be required, and even that may not be needed if the modulus is something like 256.

@CortAmmon: I don't know what high-level or mixed-level languages supported modular addressing, but would expect such a notion to be convenient in many graphics or digital signal processing applications.

The earliest of which I know is the Icon Programming Language (1977) which allowed negative indexing of lists (one dimensional arrays) and strings as well as slices counting from the end.
An overview of Icon (thanks to qwr) is "The Icon Programming Language: An Overview" and the full reference is "The Icon Programming Language".
P.S. I don't recall if SNOBOL had the same feature.

Do you have documentation that it has this feature in 1977?

https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/icon/ftp/doc/tr78_3.pdf you can add this to your answer

Also I'll look at SNOBOL later

SNOBOL4 does not implement negative indexes as meaning 'from the end'.  And nor could it, since negative indexes are just ordinary indexes in a suitably-declared array.ARRAY('-10:10') is a 21-element array with index running from -10 to +19.

I couldn't find indexing at all in SNOBOL3 http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/sds/9xx/940/ucbProjectGenie/mcjones/30.50.70.pdf so safe to say it never had negative indexing.

@qwr - this paper on the history of SNOBOL by Griswold says that arrays (and structures) were introduced in SNOBOL4, thus backing up your comment.

Uh, in my example of ARRAY('-10:10') the upper bound of +19 is a typo, not an indication of utterly bizarre declaration semantics.

Negative index is common in newer languages with slices like C#, Julia, Ruby, Perl. Among them Perl is the oldest one, which was first released publicly in 1987
Unfortunately I don't know when the negative index feature was introduced, but it definitely existed at least in Perl 4. I've checked the Perl 1.0 source code from the links below but can't confirm if it supports negative index or not, and I couldn't find Perl 2.0 or 3.0 yet

https://st.aticpan.org/source/RCLAMP/perl-1.0_16/
https://github.com/AnaTofuZ/Perl-1.0
https://github.com/kaworu/perl1


Ah I was pretty sure but not positive that it was Perl where I first saw it.

https://st.aticpan.org/source/RCLAMP/perl-1.0_16/array.c looks like it doesn't handle keys < 0 but I haven't tested

I tried out the docker image of the kaworu/perl1 and negative indexing returns nothing, like out-of-bounds indexing. perl -e '@days = ("Mon","Tue","Wed"); print ($days[-1],"\n");'

AFAICS neither does 4.000 or 4.036; the code here was introduced somewhere in the lost series of patches between 5.000alpha9 (May '94) and 5.000 (Oct '94).

However splice supported negative indexing from its introduction in 3.0p13 (Mar 1990).

Technically, C# doesn't use negative indexing like Python does.  If you use -1 as an index, it will error out.  C# uses a different syntax for negative indexing, ^1, to avoid situations where the value is computed, rather than a compile-time constant, and the computation erroneously results in a negative number which then gets interpreted as a from-the-end index rather than as an error.

@MasonWheeler - thanks for posting that. Though I like and use 'negative indexing' in Python code, it really does seem like an accident waiting to happen.

The earliest I can find is the documentation of Mathematica 1.0 (1988).

You may want to give readers a bit more time to add their knowledge. That is beside it making sense to let Tofro write his own answer when he stings it is one.

@Raffzahn - 'stings' ?

@dave Err ... my bad, should read 'thinks'  as in "Let Tofro write his own answer when he thinks it is one". (He wrote this 'answer' after Tofro mentioned Mathematica doing this in a comment (now moved to char - another proof why those moves are stupid)) Sorry.
